# how to add extra filter to custom product reports in magento

Tags: magento, filter, grid, block

I am doing custom product reports in magento. I followed as the steps in the [url](http://wrightcreativelabs.com/create-a-custom-magento-report-product-skus-in-new-orders/#comment-291)

But how can I add extra filter after "from:","to:","show By:". I know where to edit in core file(adminhtml/default/default/template/report/grid.php). But it is not the correct way. how to override this filter block for custom reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for you swift reply Fabian Blechschmidt...almost I did the same but I overrode the template file.

```
adminhtml/default/mytheme/template/reportnew/grid.php
```

I just copied all the report files to mytheme/template folder (reportnew) and its working fine.

I have managed to add two extra fields viz country and a custom attribute "myattrib". But now I am unable to fetch the values from the grid to the model so that I can filter results based on these fields.

Thanks Murali

Comment: HI have you achieved this ? if yes please put the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit the template file, implement your own module, [add a section to the](http://www.suncrescent.net/2009/03/magento-how-to-change-the-admin-theme/) `config.xml`

```
<config>
    <stores>
        <admin>
            <!-- override default admin design package and theme -->
            <design>
                <package>
                    <name>default</name>
                </package>
                <theme>
                    <default>CHOOSE_A_NICE_NAME</default>
                </theme>
            </design>
        </admin>
    </stores>
</config>
```

and then start changing your template in

```
adminhtml/default/CHOOSE_A_NICE_NAME/template/report/grid.php
```